# Link circles to the middle circle with CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I draw a line to link all circle to the red one ?
I would like each circle join the red circle.

I have tried with :before and :after but as I'm new it's not easy.

Thanks.

```css
.circle-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 24em;
    height: 24em;
    padding: 2.8em;
    /*2.8em = 2em*1.4 (2em = half the width of a link with img, 1.4 = sqrt(2))*/
    margin: 1.75em auto 0;
}
.circle-container span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    margin: -2em;
    border: dashed 1px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.center { background: red; }
.item1 { transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(12em) rotate(90deg); }
.item2 { transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(12em) rotate(60deg); }
.item3 { transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(12em) rotate(30deg); }
.item4 { transform: rotate(0deg) translate(12em) rotate(0deg); }
.item5 { transform: rotate(30deg) translate(12em) rotate(-30deg); }
.item6 { transform: rotate(60deg) translate(12em) rotate(-60deg); }
.item7 { transform: rotate(90deg) translate(12em) rotate(-90deg); }
```

```html
<div class="circle-container">
    <span class="center">MENU</span>

    <span class="item1">ITEM 1</span>
    <span class="item2">ITEM 2</span>
    <span class="item3">ITEM 3</span>
    <span class="item4">ITEM 4</span>
    <span class="item5">ITEM 5</span>
    <span class="item6">ITEM 6</span>
    <span class="item7">ITEM 7</span>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a simpler way, in terms of the CSS needed, using rotate if it is acceptable to alter the HTML. Is that allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Pseudo-elements as an Extension

Note, in the provided example, the HTML has been altered for [aesthetic](http://thomasart325.weebly.com/uploads/3/0/7/4/30742183/art_talk_chapter_2-lesson_4.pdf) and [semantic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics) reasons -- there is nothing wrong with your HTML (unless we are talking about aesthetics and/or semantics ).

For each `.item*`, add either an `::after` or `::before` pseudo-element styled as a `12em` wide element with a visible `border-bottom` (simular to a `<hr>`). See **Figure I**.

### Figure I

```css
a:not(.center)::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -6em;
  top: 2em;
  width: 12em;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 0.25em solid red;
}
```

Then adjust each line using it's parent's first `transform: rotate()` value, then move the line with `transform: translate()` and `transform-origin`, see **Figure II** which shows how `.item1::after` is styled.

### Figure II

```css
.item1 {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(12em) rotate(90deg);
}

.item1::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-7.5em, 2em);
  transform-origin: center bottom
}
```

### Example

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 24em;
  height: 24em;
  padding: 2.8em;
  margin: 1.75em auto 0;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  margin: -2em;
  border: dashed 1px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

a:not(.center)::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -6em;
  top: 2em;
  width: 12em;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 0.25em solid red;
}

.center {
  background: red;
}

.item1 {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(12em) rotate(90deg);
}

.item1::after {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-7.5em, 2em);
  transform-origin: center bottom
}

.item2 {
  transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(12em) rotate(60deg);
}

.item2::after {
  transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(-6.5em, 2em);
  transform-origin: center bottom
}

.item3 {
  transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(12em) rotate(30deg);
}

.item3::after {
  transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(-6em, 1em);
  transform-origin: center
}

.item4 {
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(12em) rotate(0deg);
}

.item4::after {
  transform: translateX(-5.75em);
  transform-origin: center
}

.item5 {
  transform: rotate(30deg) translate(12em) rotate(-30deg);
}

.item5::after {
  transform: rotate(30deg) translate(-6.25em, -1.5em);
  transform-origin: center
}

.item6 {
  transform: rotate(60deg) translate(12em) rotate(-60deg);
}

.item6::after {
  transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-6.75em, -2em);
  transform-origin: center
}

.item7 {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(12em) rotate(-90deg);
}

.item7::after {
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-7.75em, -2em);
  transform-origin: center
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#/" class="center">MENU</a>

  <a href="#/" class="item1">ITEM 1</a>
  <a href="#/" class="item2">ITEM 2</a>
  <a href="#/" class="item3">ITEM 3</a>
  <a href="#/" class="item4">ITEM 4</a>
  <a href="#/" class="item5">ITEM 5</a>
  <a href="#/" class="item6">ITEM 6</a>
  <a href="#/" class="item7">ITEM 7</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found these JS functions, where you pass the form and to elements, as well as a line with a predefined style:

```js
    function adjustLine(from, to, line){
    
      var fT = from.offsetTop  + from.offsetHeight/2;
      var tT = to.offsetTop      + to.offsetHeight/2;
      var fL = from.offsetLeft + from.offsetWidth/2;
      var tL = to.offsetLeft     + to.offsetWidth/2;
      
      var CA   = Math.abs(tT - fT);
      var CO   = Math.abs(tL - fL);
      var H    = Math.sqrt(CA*CA + CO*CO);
      var ANG  = 180 / Math.PI * Math.acos( CA/H );
    
      if(tT > fT){
          var top  = (tT-fT)/2 + fT;
      }else{
          var top  = (fT-tT)/2 + tT;
      }
      if(tL > fL){
          var left = (tL-fL)/2 + fL;
      }else{
          var left = (fL-tL)/2 + tL;
      }
    
      if(( fT < tT && fL < tL) || ( tT < fT && tL < fL) || (fT > tT && fL > tL) || (tT > fT && tL > fL)){
        ANG *= -1;
      }
      top-= H/2;
    
      line.style["-webkit-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
      line.style["-moz-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
      line.style["-ms-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
      line.style["-o-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
      line.style["-transform"] = 'rotate('+ ANG +'deg)';
      line.style.top    = top+'px';
      line.style.left   = left+'px';
      line.style.height = H + 'px';
    }
```

Link to the original project: https://jsfiddle.net/rdamasceno/o3Lroapa/5/